# How to display the path of a Decision Tree for test samples?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, decision-tree

I'm using [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) from scikit-learn to classify some multiclass data. I found many posts describing how to display the decision tree path, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214350/color-of-the-node-of-tree-with-graphviz-using-class-names/43218264#43218264), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118195/getting-decision-path-to-a-node-in-sklearn), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn). However, all of them describe how to display the tree for the **trained** data. It makes sense, because [`export_graphviz`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) only requires a fitted model.

My question is how do I visualize the tree on the **test samples** (preferably by `export_graphviz`). I.e. after fitting the model with `clf.fit(X[train], y[train])`, and then predicting the results for the test data by `clf.predict(X[test])`, I want to visualize the decision path used for predicting the samples `X[test]`. Is there a way to do that?

**Edit:**

I see that the path can be printed using [decision_path](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py). If there's a way to get a `DOT` output as of `export_graphviz` to display it, that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get the path which is taken for a particular sample in a decision tree you could use [`decision_path`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path). It returns a sparse matrix with the decision paths for the provided samples.

Those decision paths can then be used to color/label the tree generated via `pydot`. This requires overwriting the color and the label (which results in a bit of ugly code).

**Notes**

- `decision_path` can take samples from the training set or new values
- you can go wild with the colors and change the color according to the number of samples or whatever other visualization might be needed

**Example**

In the example below a visited node is colored in green, all other nodes are white.

[image]

```
import pydotplus
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42)
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,
                                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                                class_names=iris.target_names,
                                filled=True, rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)

# empty all nodes, i.e.set color to white and number of samples to zero
for node in graph.get_node_list():
    if node.get_attributes().get('label') is None:
        continue
    if 'samples = ' in node.get_attributes()['label']:
        labels = node.get_attributes()['label'].split('<br/>')
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            if label.startswith('samples = '):
                labels[i] = 'samples = 0'
        node.set('label', '<br/>'.join(labels))
        node.set_fillcolor('white')

samples = iris.data[129:130]
decision_paths = clf.decision_path(samples)

for decision_path in decision_paths:
    for n, node_value in enumerate(decision_path.toarray()[0]):
        if node_value == 0:
            continue
        node = graph.get_node(str(n))[0]            
        node.set_fillcolor('green')
        labels = node.get_attributes()['label'].split('<br/>')
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            if label.startswith('samples = '):
                labels[i] = 'samples = {}'.format(int(label.split('=')[1]) + 1)

        node.set('label', '<br/>'.join(labels))

filename = 'tree.png'
graph.write_png(filename)
```