# Plot a path of the decision tree in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

The answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878247/how-to-display-the-path-of-a-decision-tree-for-test-samples) can highlight the path of a decision tree, but is there any way to only plot a single path of a decision tree in python? My decision tree is built by tree.DecisionTreeClassifier() in scikit-learn and visualized by Graphviz as follows:

```
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,
                 feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                 class_names=iris.target_names,
                 filled=True, rounded=True,
                 special_characters=True)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
```

The reason for doing this is when the decision tree is deep, there will be a large number of nodes and the tree is too narrow to be used as a figure of an article.

This action can be done by manually editing the dot_data file generated by the function export_graphviz(), i.e., manually deleting the lines of the dot_data file as follows and leave the lines representing the path I want to plot.

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box, style="filled, rounded", color="black", fontname="helvetica"] ;
edge [fontname="helvetica"] ;
0 [label=<petal width (cm) &le; 0.8<br/>gini = 0.667<br/>samples = 150<br/>value = [50, 50, 50]<br/>class = setosa>, fillcolor="#ffffff"] ;
1 [label=<gini = 0.0<br/>samples = 50<br/>value = [50, 0, 0]<br/>class = setosa>, fillcolor="#e58139"] ;
...
```

This action can surely be done by python, but is there any simple way to do this? For example, **is it possible to change some parameters of the existing functions to plot a single path of a decision tree in python?** Thanks for helping!

Comment: If you can think of how to do it by hand, there's likely a way to do it in Python - what have you tried yourself? Please share code of your best attempt so far and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks for your suggestion! I have edit the question according to your valuable suggestion!